# Need some help for bodyparser

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, body-parser

So I'm trying to access data from my frontend using bodyparser, but I can't manage to get it working. Here is my code:

```
app.post("/deletetodo", (req, res) => {
    createNewTodo.findOne({ "usersID": req.body.accountName, "todo": req.body.delete_todo }, (err, todo) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        if(todo) {
            todo.remove();
            res.redirect("/api/user")
        } else {
            console.log(req.body.delete_todo + " " + req.body.accountName)
            res.redirect("/api/user")

        }
    }) 
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

For some reason, I get the value of req.body.delete_todo, but not the value of req.body.accountName, which returns **undefined**. And I know it's not a matter of syntax error because I litteraly use req.body.accountName on other post requests with the exact same syntax on the exact same page in the same file.

EDIT:
I'm trying to access the name of a todo which the users clicks on, and his/ hers account name, to search for them in my mongoDB database and then delete that todo. I get the value of which todo is clicked on but as mentioned, not the clients username (req.body.accountName).

Here is my frontend code:

```
<nav class="todo-nav">
    <span class="logo">Todoish</span>
    <span class="account">Logged in as <b>{{ accountStuff }}</b> | <a class="logout-btn" href="http://localhost:8000/api/user/logout">Logout</a></span>
</nav>
<form action="http://localhost:8000/addtodo" class="create-todo-form" method="POST">
    <p class="signupMsg">{{ todoErrMsg }}</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Todo..." class="todo-input" name="todo" required>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="accountName" value="{{accountStuff}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">
</form>
<div class="list-of-todos">
    {{#each todos}}
        <div class="todo">
            <span>{{this}}</span>
            <form class="todo-btn-form" method="POST">
            <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="accountName" value=" 
            {{accountStuff}}">
                <button value="{{this}}" class="edit-btn">Edit</button>
                <button value="{{this}}" name="delete_todo" method="POST" formaction="http://localhost:8000/deletetodo" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: please add code of API request from frontend and also mention what do you want to do with this API

Comment: Please check in network console whether you are sending the accountName key value or not.

Comment: It sends the key but there is no value, it just says 

accountName: 
delete_todo: (the value of the todo that I clicked)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Apparently I couldn't use accountStuff inside my foreach loop containing my todos sent from the backend. Instead I had to put the accountStuff input outside my foreach, but still being inside my form.

```
<div class="list-of-todos">
    <form action="http://localhost:8000/deletetodo" class="todo-btn-form" method="POST">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="usersName" value={{accountStuff}}> //This input had to be outside of the #each loop but still in form 
        {{#each todos}}
            <div class="todo">
                <span>{{this}}</span>
                <button value="{{this}}" class="edit-btn">Edit</button>
                <button value="{{this}}" name="delete_todo" method="POST" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
            </div>
         {{/each}}
    </form>
</div>
```